# Rider showing MvcApplication (load failed)

Tags: linux, .net-core, rider

I just installed JetBrains Rider and initiated a .net core MVC app. It finished generating the initial files and shows MvcApplication(load failed). I installed .net core from its own website and 'dotnet' command is working as dotnetcli is also installed. The error message displayed is **"Solution 'MvcApplication' load failed. Rider was unable to detect a Mono runtime on this machine. We strongly recommend to install the latest version of Mono."**
Why is mono required if I have already installed dotnet core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now Rider doesn't support .net core msbuild. You have to install mono and msbuild along with .net core, see https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207335749-Using-Project-Rider-under-Linux-prerequisites
We're going to fix it soon =)

Comment: I think it should be done in 1 month =) The main issue - we have to move some our logic to .net core to use .net core msbuild. And it's not so easy =)